# Are “rescind”, “repeal”, and “annul” perfect synonyms?

Tags: meaning, verbs, synonyms

What are the best places to use these three verbs:

- rescind
- repeal
- annul

Are these all exactly similar in meaning, or are they supposed to be used for different purposes?

Comment: Have you looked up the meanings in a dictionary? If not, please do so and then tell us where your confusion lies. Please do some research yourself instead of expecting others to do it all for you.

Comment: Yes I did lookup from the dictionary and all three words looked the same. That's why I asked the question - and my question is basically on where exactly we can 'use' the words.

Comment: These are often legal terms; there are distinct differences between them but they can be quite confusing even for native speakers too. One thing I am sure of (and I'll leave the rest to others better qualified) is that you can annul a marriage, which is very different from a divorce. I don't think you can *annul* a law, that would be like saying it never existed, or had good cause to exist.http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annulment

Comment: Thanks for your explanation MARI-LOU A. I'm finding it difficult to figure out differences between similar words like these since I'm not a native speaker.

Comment: A word of advice, it is always a good idea to wait a bit before awarding an answer. Someone else might provide a more detailed account of the various differences. If that does happen, you can still *upvote* (arrow up) their answer.

Comment: RE: _I'm finding it difficult to figure out differences between similar words like these since I'm not a native speaker._ In that case, you probably want to ask your questions at the site for [ell.SE].

Comment: Close-voters: Wiktionary defines _rescind_ as “To **repeal, annul,** or declare void; to take (something such as a rule or contract) out of effect” and _repeal_ as “To cancel, invalidate, **annul**.” Other dictionaries produce similar results. Somebody who doesn't already understand the fine distinctions of these words isn't going to figure them out by looking them up in a dictionary.

Comment: @BraddSzonye Agreed and voted to re-open.

Comment: There are no exact synonyms.

Comment: @Rajeev Sampath why did you not post whatever your dictionary and/or thesaurus searches revealed, please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even though the words are synonymous, some of them are used more traditionally in some contexts.

For example, *laws* are usually [repealed](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=repeal+the+law%2Cannul+the+law%2Crescind+the+law&year_start=1920&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=), *marriages* are usually [annulled](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=repeal+the+marriage%2Cannul+the+marriage%2Crescind+the+marriage&year_start=1920&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=), and *orders* are usually [rescinded](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=repeal+the+order%2Cannul+the+order%2Crescind+the+order&year_start=1920&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=).

In [other cases](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=repeal+the+treaty%2Cannul+the+treaty%2Crescind+the+treaty&year_start=1970&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=), it's [not so clear](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=repeal+the+decision%2Cannul+the+decision%2Crescind+the+decision&year_start=1920&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=).

(Click on the links for relevant Ngrams).

<sub>**EDIT**</sub>

NOAD has this usage note under its entry for *void*:

> To *void* a check, to *invalidate* a claim, to *abrogate* a law, and to *annul* a marriage all refer to the same basic activity, which is putting an end to something or depriving it of validity, force, or authority. But these verbs are not always interchangeable.
>
> *Annul* is the most general term, meaning to end something that exists or to declare that it never really existed (: the charter was annulled before it could be challenged).
>
> *Abrogate* implies the exercise of legal authority (: Congress abrogated the treaty between the two warring factions), while nullify means to deprive something of its value or effectiveness (: nullify the enemy's attempt to establish communications).
>
> *Void* and *invalidate* are often used interchangeably as they both mean to make null or worthless (: void a legal document by tearing it up; invalidate a check by putting the wrong date on it).
>
> *Negate* means to prove an assertion false (: her version of the story negated everything her brother had said) or to nullify or make something ineffective (: the study's findings were negated by its author's arrest for fraud).

NOAD also defines *repeal* as:

> **repeal** (*verb*)
> revoke or annul (a law or congressional act) : *the legislation was repealed five months later*.

So, repeal seems best suited for legislation, whereas I believe the equivalent term for judicial decisions would be *overturn*.

Lastly:

> **rescind** (*verb*) revoke, cancel, or repeal (a law, order, or agreement) : *the government eventually rescinded the directive*.

I'd be inclined to avoid *rescind* when *repeal* would work well (Mitt Romney pledged to *repeal* Obamacare, not *rescind* it), but *rescind* can be a good word to use when *repeal* or *annul* seem to be the wrong word. Unfortunately, I don't think there's a simple litmus test that will always determine when one word would sound less appropriate than another in every context. Since *repeal* is embedded in the definition of *rescind*, it would be hard to say that it would be "wrong" to use the words interchangeably, but there are some contexts where one will sound markedly more suitable than another.

Comment: I *really* don't think this helpful. 'Laws are usually repealed', rather than annulled, because it is commoner for legislators to change their minds than for a constitutional body to declare that the law was improper and had no effect. In contexts where precision is needed, how common a phrase is does not help with its meaning.

Comment: @Tim: Fair enough, although the Ngrams themselves have plenty of additional [links](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22rescind%20the%20law%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1991,cd_max:2000&lr=lang_en) where more information can be examined. I suppose a more detailed answer could be drafted; at least this question isn't closed yet, should anyone care to take on the challenge. You've provided a good start.

Comment: @Tim: I took a stab at providing a more substantial answer. The [dictionary meanings are quite basic](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/rescind), so it's hard to authoritatively talk about what these three words "mean", which is why I thought some common associations might be helpful. Yet it was true that my initial answer was perhaps not as helpful as it could have been, so I've tried to bolster it a bit.